# PlotLegends not respecting PlotRange in ArrayPlot and MatrixPlot

Tags: plotting

I have a matrix that I want to plot. This matrix has data with values ranging from 1400 to -50. If I do

```
ArrayPlot[data, PlotRange->{All, 40}, PlotLegends->Automatic, 
 DataRange->{{-Sqrt[2] Pi, Sqrt[2] Pi}, {0.001, 2}}, AspectRatio->1]
```

I get

[image]

The legend correctly reflects the `PlotRange` I specified. However, if I do

```
ArrayPlot[data, PlotRange -> {All, 40}, PlotLegends -> Automatic, 
 DataRange -> {{-Sqrt[2] Pi, Sqrt[2] Pi}, {0.001, 2}}, 
 AspectRatio -> 1, ColorFunction -> "M10DefaultDensityGradient"]
```

I get

[image]

I believe the `ColorFunction` correctly only took in the data specified by `PlotRange`, but the ticks in `PlotLegends` are incorrect. I can change the `PlotRange` to a specific value, for example `PlotRange->{-50, 40}`, then the legend will be correct.

For `MatrixPlot`, even providing specific values to `PlotRange` doesn't work. The legends always have the full range of the data as ticks. I'm wondering how to make the ticks in `PlotLegends` work with `PlotRange` in `ArrayPlot` and `MatrixPlot`. Thank you.